instruct GDB to load symbols with an offset
We have a firmware app (on an ARM processor) which can run on two different locations in flash:

0x60020000 (=App A)
0x60110000 (=App B)

Now I need to debug a situation on App B, so I am trying to attach the debugger (GDB, arm-none-eabi), and load symbols with an offset.
I have done this before, and I added comments how I managed to do it, but apparently I didn't record things correctly as it no longer works.
        // In order to find the magic number :
        // ./show-symbols.sh
        // add the value found at .text Offset column to start address of the application (0x6011 0000)
        // [ 3] .text             PROGBITS        600230f0 0230f0 04e654 00  AX  0   0 16
        // magic number = 0x6011 0000 + 0x230f0
        // "add-symbol-file ${workspaceRoot}/build-app/app.axf 0x601330F0",
        "add-symbol-file ${workspaceRoot}/build-app/app.axf 0x601330F0",

The show-symbols script calls arm-none-eabi-readelf on my axf (=elf) file and prints the following:
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0xc64294:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .vectors          PROGBITS        20000000 011000 000278 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 2] .got              PROGBITS        20000278 011278 002230 04  WA  0   0  4
  [ 3] .text             PROGBITS        600224b0 0134b0 08ee10 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 4] .data.dtc         PROGBITS        200024a8 0a84a8 00240c 00  WA  0   0  8
  [ 5] .data.itc         PROGBITS        00000000 0a3000 004f8c 00  AX  0   0  8
  [ 6] .data.ncache      PROGBITS        2020fe00 0aa8b4 000000 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 7] .bss              NOBITS          200048c0 0008c0 00e9d0 00  WA  0   0 64
  [ 8] .bss.oc           PROGBITS        20200000 001000 00f400 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 9] .bss.unodelink    PROGBITS        2020ff00 010f00 000100 00  WA  0   0  8
  [10] .bss.ncache       NOBITS          2020fe00 010e00 000058 00  WA  0   0 64
  [11] .heap             NOBITS          2020f400 010400 000100 00  WA  0   0  4
  [12] .heap2stackfill   NOBITS          2020f500 010400 000200 00  WA  0   0  1
  [13] .stack            PROGBITS        2020fc00 0aa8b4 000000 00   W  0   0  4
  [14] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 0aa8b4 4df305 00      0   0  1
  [15] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 589bb9 068f52 00      0   0  1
  [16] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 5f2b10 018030 00      0   0  8
  [17] .debug_rnglists   PROGBITS        00000000 60ab40 012989 00      0   0  1
  [18] .debug_macro      PROGBITS        00000000 61d4c9 0c4eed 00      0   0  1
  [19] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 6e23b6 1ca7e5 00      0   0  1
  [20] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 8acb9b 25a0ed 01  MS  0   0  1
  [21] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 b06c88 000044 01  MS  0   0  1
  [22] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 b06ccc 000036 00      0   0  1
  [23] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 b06d04 06d248 00      0   0  4
  [24] .debug_loclists   PROGBITS        00000000 b73f4c 007463 00      0   0  1
  [25] .debug_line_str   PROGBITS        00000000 b7b3af 000182 01  MS  0   0  1
  [26] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 b7b534 0463a0 10     27 12251  4
  [27] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 bc18d4 0a2888 00      0   0  1
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 c6415c 000138 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  D (mbind), y (purecode), p (processor specific)

Following my own comments from the past, I would need to:

find the offset in the output for .text = 0134b0
add the app address to that address = 134b0 + 60110000
launch gdb with pre attach command "add-symbol-file ${workspaceRoot}/build-app/app.axf 0x601234B0"

But when I then break the app, the stack trace is wrong. I should end up in FreeRTOS like 99.99999% of the time, I never do. I am 100% sure the app is idle-ing in FreeRTOS, so I am 100% sure my instruction for add-symbol-file is wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong...
Reading the docs doesn't help me either. I tried the -o  but learned this this offset is applied to all other section than the .text section which is not what I am looking for either.
I lack knowledge on GDB, clearly. Hoping for some guidance here

Just create a 2nd link to the absolute address.  Re-use the objects from the first link address 0x60020000, but use the 2nd link address 'elf' for debugging.  The debugger doesn't look at instructions on the target (but they should be the same).  Ie, the only thing changing between images is the symbol tables (non loadable data).  Then you don't have to script things with math and obscure gdb documentation.

See: How to disassemble a memory range for some more information on the topic.  So, your information that it works might be correct.  But it might depend on tooling.  The link at different addresses will work no matter what.

Err, actually, if you debug on the ARM as a gdb host, then the symbol-file may work (if that is what you do).  It is possible that tooling updates allow it to work for cross gdb, but this was not my experience.  But in most cases, there are only two locations (an A/B) and it is easy to create two images.  A great benefit is that old/new apps can exist.  Some confirmation of functionality of the new image on the device may occur before deleting the older copy.  You can revert to the old image, if functionality fails, which may make a user happy.  Good luck.

the symbol-file worked just fine....! thx a lot

Ah, I see.  The data was not relocated in my case.  Either your data is relocated as well or you are not examining program variables (globals/statics).  This is why I created two images just for the 'symbols'.  It is not a 'problem with the tools', but the way symbol-file offset works.  It is all or nothing.  Anyways, glad it is working for you.
